# Proving that $(p \to \lnot p) \vdash \lnot p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm working through Tomassi's *Logic* book and I've come across an exercise that challenges you to find a proof for $(p \to \lnot p) \vdash \lnot p$ in 11 steps (p. 82, Exercise 3.2.1.10). Only the following strategies have been mentioned so far in the book:

1. $\land$ - Introduction and $\land$ - Elimination
2. Modus Ponens and Modus Tollens
3. Conditional Proof
4. Double Negation Elimination and Double Negation Introduction
5. $\Leftrightarrow$ - Introduction and $\Leftrightarrow$ - Elimination
6. Deduction Theorem

Other than stating the premise the only strategy I can think of from here is to assume $p$ and then free it from its assumption, but I'm not sure where else to go from here. Any help would be appreciated on what the next steps should be.

Comment: $A\implies B$ means $\lnot A \lor B$

Comment: [Here's a useful tool.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(P%E2%86%92%C2%ACP)%E2%86%92%C2%ACP)

Comment: What proof *system* are you using?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I believe a Hilbert proof system, although the book has not shown any of the axioms associated with that proof system yet.

Comment: You haven't said so, but are you sure you cannot use proof by contradiction? If you can use it, start by assuming $P\implies \neg P$, then assume $P$.

Comment: Proof by contradiction hasn't been introduced yet either. Here is a clue that the author gives on the exercise that I recently noticed: "This proof requires that you first derive the relevant conditional and then apply MT. In each case, you will have to derive the conditional by augmenting the premises . . .  If the formula you want is already a negated sentence-letter try assuming the original sentence letter un-negated. Finally, make sure that the conditional you derive has as its antecedent the formula which you ultimately want to negate by MT."

Comment: @Cizox It's not a Hilbert-style axiomatic proof system. It's more of a Sequent Calculus ... having MT as one of the rules is unusual though ... but this is how you can avoid Proof by Contradiction, which is a more standard rule to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do it in 9 steps:

\begin{array}{llll}
\{1\}&1.&P \to \neg P&Premise\\
\{2\}&2.&P&Premise\\
\{2\}&3.&\neg \neg P&2 \ DNI\\
\{1,2\}&4.&\neg P&1,2 \ MP\\
\{2\}&5.&(P\to \neg P) \to \neg P&1,4\ CP\\
\{2\}&6.&\neg (P \to \neg P)&3,5\ MT\\
\{ \}&7.&P\to \neg(P \to \neg P)&2,6 \ CP\\
\{1\}&8.&\neg \neg (P \to \neg P)&1 \ DNI\\
\{1\}&9.&\neg P&7,8\ MT\\
\end{array}

Comment: Are you allowed to discharge the premise on line (1) before discharging that on line(2) as is done of line (5)? It doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, that's ok. This is one of the big diffreences betweeen sequent systems and Fitch-style (and what I would call '!natural Deduction' systems): in the latter you have to follow a strict 'first-in last-out' policy for discharging assumptins... which is reflected by the nested subproof structures. But in Sequent systems there is no such reauirement; there, you simply move from 'this follows from that, therefore such follows from so'

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$(p \to \lnot p) \vdash \lnot p$$

By conditional exchange

$\neg p \lor \neg p$

If the conditional exchange hasn't been introduced yet (which I see now that it hasn't), you can use a conditional proof and assume $p$. Then, by modus tollens, you can derive $\neg p$